# how can I solve this loop?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I am currently building a windows form application and I have got the next problem,
I can't declare a variable global because the syntax im using won't allow me to do that, also, i need to declare the variable in the method it self and at last, it must loop so its able to count. This is what I have got so far:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             int i;
             m_bIsTimerOn = true;
             while (m_bIsTimerOn)
                 {
                        i++;
                        label1->Text = (i.ToString());
                 }
         }

private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             m_bIsTimerOn = false;
             timer1->Enabled = false;
         }
```

m_bIsTimerOn is a globally boolean. As you might see here my problem is if i press button1 the program is just stuck in the while loop. I would like to know that the moment you press button2 the while loop stops I also would like to know if this is even possible. If you could response in c++ that would also be fine.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to increment `i` while timer is on. If you need to update `i` for each timer tick then it's pretty easy, remove that loop (and that variable BTW) and simply do update inside timer `Tick` event:

```
private:
    int _i;

    void button1_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e) {
         _i = 0;
        timer1->Enabled = true;
    }

    void _timer1_Tick(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e) {
        label1->Text = (i++).ToString();
    }

    void button2_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e) {
        timer1->Enabled = false;
    }
```

If i must be updated independently from timer ticks then you have to move it to a `BackgroundWorker` or simply in event handler for `Application::Idle:`

```
    void OnIdle(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e) {
        label1->Text = (_i++).ToString();
    }

    void button1_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e) {
         _i = 0;
        Application::Idle += gcnew EventHandler(this, Form1::OnIdle);
        timer1->Enabled = true;
    }

    void button2_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e) {
        Application::Idle -= gcnew EventHandler(this, Form1::OnIdle);
        timer1->Enabled = false;
    }
```

As final note: you may even keep your loop as is and put a call to `Application::DoEvents()` just after your `label1->Text = (i.ToString());` but this will probably consumes a lot of CPU, slow down your application and open your code to reentrancy, I'd really avoid something like that...

Comment: I cant use I like that because the syntax I am using won't allow me to use it like that. The code i provided you from is just a sample. I needs to be made in the same method as it is being used in.

Comment: @Thealon I added a last paragraph (and a second solution) about that but let me say "syntax I'm using" is pretty curious sentence. UI is single threaded then keep a tight loop running while user can still invoke other methods is a bad bad idea. Maybe you'd better to post some code more similar to what you're really using: few changes in design will make that better (to read as: if your loop performs more things than it should be moved to a **separate thread** with proper synchronization).

Comment: I added the syntax i think it isn't going to help you

Comment: @Thealon there you can use 2nd example (OnIdle) or - better - a BackgroundWorker (a separate thread with some facilities for WinForms integration). 2nd step I'd get rid of C stuff like printf and fflush (move to .NET System.Console).

Comment: Where do you define "I" in your second sample?

Comment: @Thealon same place of 1st example, a private member variable. (in OnIdle should be "_i" not "i").

Answer (score 0):

Your program is in endless loop because the while loop prevents the messages from getting processed and hence your button2_Click does not get invoked. To make you application capable of processing the messages that occurs, add Application.DoEvents() in your loop as:

```
while (m_bIsTimerOn)
{
    i++;
    label1->Text = (i.ToString());

    Application.DoEvents();   // causes the application to handle pending events
}
```

So now, if you press the second button, m_bIsTimerOn will become false and your loop will terminate.

Comment: -1 I posted same solution in my answer with a note to **do not use it**. Why? Because it'll make his code reentrant. User can click again button1 (for example) to make any other bad things asynchronously. Take some time to read [this article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/is-doevents-evil/). Something to avoid 99.99% of times (and this isn't that 0.01)

Comment: Dear @Adriano, I very well understand the issues associated with this approach (if this approach is used individually). As I am also aware that most of the time the code provided in the question is not the complete question but only a snippet to help others understand the issue and provide a solution; hence I just provided a solution which can be used in such a place.

Comment: An example could be, while reading and processing a large video file, the variable 'i' can be used to count the video frames processed, the rest of the code could be to process the video frame, while the second button could be to 'stop processing'.... This is just an example off my head right now, but you can think of many others alike. :) ............ I also understand that Threading would be better approach but many times you do not have the luxury to change the architecture of already functional application :(